# How to add signature to powershell code creating new mail?

Tags: powershell, outlook

I want signatures to show up when creating new message as they do with Ctrl+N?
Here is my code:

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = "random.dude@email.com"
$Mail.Subject = "data for Subject"
$Mail.Body ="Example of body..."
$Mail.Signature = "Primary"
$inspector = $mail.GetInspector
$inspector.Display()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could refer to the below code:

```
    $Signature = "`n`nBest Regards,`nYourName`nyour@email.com"
    $Mail.Body = "Si comunica che i pacchetti harvest $esito.`nSi rimanda alle verifiche del caso `nSaluti$Signature"
```

For more information, Please refer to this link:

[Powershell email signature](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/222116f3-fdb5-4c6d-9c09-cc0d4e4aa4c1/powershell-email-signature?forum=winserverpowershell)

Answer (score 1):

The signature is added when `Display` is called as long as the message body is unmodified.
This means you must call `Display` first, and **then** merge your data with the body that the message has at this moment.

Also keep in mind that to keep the signature formatting, you must use the `HTMLBody` property rather than plain text `Body`. And you cannot simply concatenate two HTML strings - they must be merged.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, it exposes [RDOSignature](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosignature.htm).`ApplyTo` method, which allows to insert signature into an existing message.